# how repeat all child id for multiple parent id in view mysql

Tags: mysql, jstree

i create this view in mysql:

[image]

how change to this view in mysql:

[image]

I used jstree and `id` Can not duplicate, so how change `id=parent id` to new `id=parent id`:
example: `id=11` and `parent id=11` changed to `id=100` and `parent id=100`

Comment: what do you mean `changed to id=100 and parent id=100` you need to update the id? it cannot be done if your id is your `primary key`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select Case when id = 11 then 100 else id end
```

This Method could be create another field if you want but the value of your table still remains and nothing changes happen.

Answer (score 0):

tanks,
plaeas view images, how from image 1(that is view in miysql) to image 2

[i create this view in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZafh.png)

[how change to this view in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUfJA.png)